# SQLite UNIQUE conflict resolution ordering

Tags: sqlite

I've got a SQLite table with two constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER,
                UNIQUE (b, c), PRIMARY KEY (a, c));
```

I'd like to do an `INSERT` that ignores records that violate the `(a, c)` constraint, even if the `(b, c)` constraint is also violated, but fails if *only* the `(b, c)` constraint is violated.

In other words, if I start with this:

```
 INSERT INTO t (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

This should silently do nothing:

```
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

but this should be an error:

```
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 2, 3);
```

If I try to do this with the relatively new PostgreSQL-like UPSERT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT (a, c) DO NOTHING;
```

it does what I want *with SQLite 3.26*, but it fails due to the `(b, c`) constraint violation on SQLite 3.24, and the [changelog](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) makes it seem like that might be an accident, rather than an indication that the behavior I want is guaranteed.

If I instead set the conflict resolution when defining the constraint,

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER,
                UNIQUE (b, c), PRIMARY KEY (a, c) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

then I get the behavior I want with both versions (good), but I am left wondering if I am still relying on undefined behavior (bad).

In other words, is there any guarantee on what the behavior will be if multiple constraints are violated, but with different (explicit or implicit) conflict handling?

FWIW, the conflict resolution order doesn't seem related to the order in which the constraints are defined - in either of the above cases, swapping the constraint definition order does not change the behavior.